# How do I ship a set of authority certificates in Thunderbird?

Tags: certificates, thunderbird

I need to distribute Thunderbird to the employees of my company and they must be able to recognize our certification authority as valid. As the data from root certificates is present in `cert.db` at the users home at `.thunderbird` folder I could not find a way to ship it within the application.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I can answer my own question. Thunderbird allows you to place files under /thunderbird/defaults/profile which will be distributed to all user accounts created upon the invocation of that binary.

So I added the cert8.db under //defaults/profile and my isp configuration as an .xml under //isp and now autoconfig works like a charm.